# Html, CSS vertical align a menu

Tags: html, css, menu, html-lists

I'm trying to make a menu, but I'm having trouble centering the text to the middle.

```
<div id="menucontainer">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li> | 
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li> | 
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Projects", "Projects", "Home")</li> | 
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Forum", "Forum", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
        </div>


#menu
{
    background-image: url("../Content/img/bg-menu.png");
    height:50px;
    padding-left:30px;
    padding-right:25px;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:20px;
    background-repeat:repeat;
    display:block;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left:55%;
    position:absolute;
    color:#aa4dc6;
}
#menu li 
{   
    display:inline;
    padding:5px 10px 9px 10px;
}
#menu a
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#606060;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    font-size:19px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

[image]

Comment: If the height of the menu is a constant thing then you should be able to do a `padding-top`.  http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/05/mastering-css-coding-getting-started/#CSS-Basics1

Comment: @Jared #menu li contains padding, but increasing the top padding doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

give it the same `line-height` as the element's `height` and the text should be properly aligned

Comment: This solution has a major drawback from a design standpoint. If by some chance the text should wrap, it will completely break the layout.

Comment: if the text should wrap - then it shouldn't be vertically aligned... this is for cases of a single line text, not for paragraphs or so

Comment: I think it's a reasonable suggestion for something like a menu, but I have seen menus where the text wraps too. It's a good answer, but worth noting anytime `line-height` is suggested as a solution.

Answer (score 7):

There are a few solutions to this problem.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4bTk5/1/) that demonstrates all of the solutions below.

First, you can try setting the `display` property to `table-cell` for the list items in the menu, and then you can use `vertical-align:middle` to center the text.

The solution would probably work well, because instead of floating the list items, you can use CSS to make them behave like table cells.

```
ul#menu {
    display: table-row;
}
ul#menu li {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Second, you can set the `line-height` property to the height of the list item. Be careful with this one though, because if the text wraps it will break the layout:

```
ul#menu li {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

Lastly, instead of setting a fixed height, you can use padding to set the height of the list items. Assuming you use the same padding for the top and bottom, the text should be aligned in the center:

```
ul#menu li {
    padding: 15px 5px 15px 5px;
}
```